# One-line list comprehension with different index using Python

Tags: python

I am creating a list in python in the following way:

```
new_points = [None] * 25
for point in points:
    new_points[point.id] = point
```

I am wondering if this can be achieved by Python one-line list comprehension. Please note that each point has a unique id. Hence two points can never have same ids.

Comment: What happens if two points have the same id?

Comment: @Holloway: Nice thought. However please note that each point has a unique id. Hence two points can never have same ids.

Comment: Please resist the temptation to use version specific tags if your question has nothing to do with a specific version of python.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. The OP may not know that her question has nothing to do with a specific version of python. Morevover, answers that are given may easily depend on the version of Python. Typically, in this case, answers for python 3 may involve generator, while not in Python2.

Comment: @Kanak Possibly, but I don't believe that applies to this question, which is why I mentioned it in the first place and removed the tag.

Comment: Have you considered using a set instead of a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you want to sort the list rather than use a comprehension.

```
new_points = sorted(points, key=lambda x:x.id)
```

The [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function takes an iterable and a key function and returns a list. In this case the key function only needs to get the id.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of this inbuilt function. (+1) Also, it is much faster than my code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to populate random locations in a list with a one-liner. But if all you want is to be able to find a point by its id, you could use a dict in stead of a list:

```
new_points = {p.id: p for p in points}
```